# Every time I deploy my api, the cached client credentials token stops working

Tags: identityserver4

So I have an app running in acceptance. It gets a client_credential token via the IdentityModel2 TokenClient

I cache this token

I can hit it 1000x and it works every time

I redeploy, that cached token now becomes invalid. Is this expected?

Comment: Are you persisting your tokens, or relying on the in-memory store ...

Comment: @Mashton I'm caching it in a SQL server cache. Locally hosted versions of this app can restart at will and the persisted token is valid

When the deployed instance is redeployed and attempts to access the cached token, IDS logs "token isvalid: false"

Comment: Exactly where is the token validation failing? In your API? Is it a JWT or reference token? Are you using a persisted signing certificate in IDS4?

Comment: I'm using a signing certificate installed on the server that IDS4 is running on, the validation fails during introspection inside of IDS4, we only use reference tokens